# Where are all the random dungeons?

Tags: diablo-iii

Depending on the zone, there may spawn a random dungeon - for example, Den of the Fallen can occasionally spawn in the Weeping Hollow, and the Scavenger's Den can spawn in the Fields of Misery.

What are all the random dungeons, and which zones do they spawn in?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

## Act I

#### Old Tristram Road

- The Cave Under the Well
- Damp Cellar
- Dank Cellar
- Mass Grave
- Musty Cellar

#### Old Tristram

- Dark Cellar
- [Quality Well](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69875/how-is-the-quality-well-in-old-tristram-unlocked) (Easter egg dungeon)

#### The Weeping Hollow

- [Den of the Fallen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68201/whats-in-the-den-of-the-fallen)

#### The Forsaken Cemetery

- [Development Hell](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67860/where-is-development-hell-and-the-unburied-jay-wilson) (Super rare Easter egg dungeon, Final Boss awards Feat of Strength)
- [False Defiled Crypts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66751/what-random-events-are-possible-in-the-false-crypts)

#### Fields of Misery

- Decaying Crypt
- [House of Curios](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70743/how-can-i-find-the-house-of-curios)
- Lost Mine
- Scavenger's Den
- Tinker's Hovel (Sheltered Cottage)
- Pillaged Home (Sheltered Cottage)
- Farmer's Cellar

#### [Southern Highlands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72456/where-are-the-spawning-areas-in-the-southern-highlands)

- [Abandoned Servant House](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73289/can-i-access-the-locked-house-that-can-appear-in-the-southern-highlands/73292#73292)
- Cave of the Moon Clan
- [The Lyceum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67855/where-is-the-lyceum)
- Watch Tower (used to be in the Northern Highlands)

#### Leoric's Hunting Grounds

- Highlands Cave

## Act II

#### Howling Plateau

- Abandoned Mineworks
- [Fuad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68101/how-do-i-defeat-fuad-the-cannibal)'s Cellar
- Sirocco Caverns

#### Black Canyon Mines

- Blood Cellar
- Deserted Cellar
- Tunnels of the Rockworm (after defeating a unique rockworm inside a Deserted Cellar)

#### Stinging Winds

- [The Crumbling Vault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67928/are-there-any-tricks-to-completing-the-crumbling-vault) (and Vault Treasure Room; [timed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67736/whatre-and-where-can-i-found-timed-dungeons))
- Hadi's Claim Mine
- The Ruins
- Chamber of the Lost Idol
- Abandoned Cellar

#### Alcarnus

- Alcarnus Cellar
- Sandy Cellar
- Town Cellar

#### Dahlgur Oasis

- Ancient Cave
- Flooded Cave
- The Forgotten Ruins
- Mysterious Cave (available after saving Zaven the Alchemist)
- Old Fisherman's Cellar
- Ransacked Cellar
- Rotting Cellar
- Storage Cellar
- Storm Cellar
- Swampy Cellar
- Tomb of Khan Dakab
- Tomb of Sardar

#### Desolate Sands

- Cave of Burrowing Horror (after defeating a unique rockworm [Shaitan the Broodmother](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75833/where-does-shaitan-the-broodmother-spawn))
- Vile Cavern
- The Veiled Treasure (Possibility of the [Ancient Device](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71984/how-can-i-find-the-ancient-device-with-less-searching))
- The [Fowl Lair](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66683/how-do-i-get-to-the-fowl-lair) (after having used the [Ancient Device](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69770/how-to-use-the-ancient-device-in-the-desolate-sands))

## Act III

#### The Arreat Gate

- Fortified Bunker
- The Barracks

#### The Battlefields

- Battlefield Stores
- The Foundry
- [Cryder's Outpost](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69610/where-is-cryders-outpost)
- The Forward Barracks

#### Fields of Slaughter

- Caverns of Frost
- Icefall Caves

#### Rakkis Crossing

- Bridge Stores
- The Underbridge

## Act IV

#### Gardens of Hope 2nd Tier

- Blessed Chancel
- [Holy Sanctum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70434/is-it-possible-to-get-all-the-slabs-tiles-in-the-holy-sanctum-and-does-it-giv)
- Radiant Chapel
- Sacellum of Virtue

## Act V

#### Westmarch Commons

- Abandoned Cultist Stores
- Contested Villa
- Hall of Dark Arts
- House of Deep Sorrow
- House of Screams
- Invaded House
- Miser's Hovel
- Old Smugglers' Warehouse
- Plague Tunnels
- Sorcerer's Room
- Tustine's Brewery
- Wynton Courtyard

#### Westmarch Heights

- Alley of Embers
- Burning Courtyard
- Clyfton Hall
- House of Corpses
- Repository of Bones
- Vermin Alley

#### Paths of the Drowned

- Bogan Warren
- Caverns of Luray
- The Hunter's Den
- Perilous Cave
- Putrid Hovel
- Winding Cave
- Wretched Hole

#### Battlefields of Eternity

- Ancient Ruins of Dholmour
- Crumbling Bunker
- Hideout of the Lost Legion
- Infested Ruins
- Occupied Ruins
- Realm of the Banished

Comment: Keep this up and I see a bounty in your future. :)

Comment: Ha, awesome.  This is fun to document; I'm surprised there's not much around the web to help draw from!

Comment: And that's why this site exists!

Comment: Which of these are timed events?

Comment: So far only The Crumbling Vault was a timed event - I'm going off of the "explore the following dungeons" style of achievement for the master lists

Comment: Nobody seems to know where The Lyceum is. I've been replaying Act 1 for hours. :-(

Comment: @sj26 It's possibly only on higher difficulties, but I don't know. It seems to be shown [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67855/where-is-the-lyceum) in Southern Highlands, but I've yet to see it. Also, I'd feel bad stealing your answer Nevir, so to save you some time I'll update you with some stuff: I found found Abandoned Cellar in Black Canyon Mines, I found The Ruins in Singing Winds, and I found Flooded Cave, Storm Cellar and Forgotten Ruins in Dahlgur Oasis. Should have more soon. Confirm at your leisure.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @skovacs1!   I've added your findings to the list; I've also switched the answer over to a community wiki (feel free to update)

Comment: @skovacs1: Are you sure Cryder's is in Rakkis Crossing? I found it in The Battlefields

Comment: @Sean You're right. I had Cryder's confused with Bridge Stores. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @sj26 the issue with the Lyceum not spawning in Southern Highlands has been fixed with patch 1.0.3 - this is now spawning although it has a reasonably low spawn rate.

Comment: Is it possible to get estimated spawn rates on these.  I am just curious about whether some areas are 10% spawn vs 25% or 60%...

Comment: Is someone updating this?

Comment: Don't some of those areas only spawn in hardcore?

Comment: I would love to see this updated. I have a fancy bounty for anyone who does :O

Comment: @spugsley Ask and ye shall receive. I edited this community wiki with locations in Act V / RoS expansion. Note that this may not be 100% exhaustive: these are simply the locations that I have found so far _and_ remembered to put in my notes.