# How do I get to the "Fowl Lair"

Tags: diablo-iii

In a [separate forum I was reading](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/diablo-3-retail-first-impressions), a poster described an easter egg area called "The Fowl Lair".  I could imagine that this is the replacement for the [Cow Level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66096/how-can-i-reach-the-secret-level-in-diablo-iii) from Diablo II, but I hope that is not the case.  How do I get to this area?  Are there any monsters or treasure to be had, or any other benefit to going there?

[image]

Comment: Given the look, we can at least narrow it down to somewhere act 2

Comment: Please link a picture when you show the map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get to the Fowl Lair you need to use the Ancient Device in Desolate Sands. It is one of the 10 possible outcomes of using the Ancient Device. So take note that not only is the spawn of the device random but there's only 10% of getting the Fowl Lair.

[Where are all the random dungeons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66418/where-are-all-the-random-dungeons/67136#67136)

This contains a community wiki of random locations and which zones they are in. It was revised to add Fowl Lair based on this forum thread:

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149619068

[image: screenshot 1]
The plateau on the map (obviously random location, but that's the shape)

[image: screenshot 2]
The Ancient Device

[image: screenshot 3]
The entrance to the Fowl Lair after succesfully spawning it using the device (took A LOT of tries)

[image: screenshot 4]
Inside the Fowl Lair

Answer (score -1):

Act 2 Blood and Sand quest. Follow the border all the way up to the top, where it starts to curve down again. After that go down the center an look for a wall. Circle around the wall until![enter image description here][1] you find what looks like a stair case, follow it up and it should be there. I just found it and I thought the Fowl pun was pretty funny after all the seriousness I've been dealing with.

Comment: Found!  Welcome to Gaming.SE!  It looks like you had a little trouble with the image markup.  Can you edit your answer to provide the image or a video of the location where you get in?

Comment: Is this in the Oasis?

Comment: This answer appears to be incorrect.