# What're and where can I found timed dungeons?

Tags: diablo-iii

I saw at Blizzcon the comment about the timed dungeons. What they really are and where can I find them? They still exist or was just an idea?

Is there a requirement to get into one?

Comment: This kind of question is better asked in the chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only seen one timed dungeon: the Crumbling Vault in the Stinging Winds area in Act 2.  You have three minutes to find the entrance to a treasure chamber in the vault containing several chests.

[image]

Comment: Oh so they did keep it in one aspect. That's cool. IIRC that's the same as from the demo I played, so they probably just didn't design any more.