# What is the timed treasure cave in desert - Act 2?

Tags: diablo-iii

Near the beginning of Act 2 while I was spelunking in the desert, I came across a cave that someone was standing outside of. He spoke of there being a treasure buried inside, but when I entered the cave, it was being timed. I only had a set number of minutes to reach a secret room I believe. Well I didn't make it to the end and the NPC said "the cave will be closed for another milennia" or something to that effect.

Does anyone know what cave I'm talking about and when/how to re-open it? I would like to try and get the treasure he spoke of.

Comment: Does leaving the game and re-entering reset the cave?

Comment: I've tried that but cannot locate the cave again, since it's randomized everytime, right?

Comment: After a quick Google [this](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5151716031) came up. Is this what you're talking about, the "crumbling cave or whatever"? That might give you some hints as to where to find the answer. I'd help more but I'm at work, can't spend too much time looking at video games!

Comment: People who come here may want to check out [Are there any tricks to completing the Crumbling Vault](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67928/are-there-any-tricks-to-completing-the-crumbling-vault).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a random event that has a chance of occurring in any game you make

I ran into it once and also failed. I'm fairly sure you have to either be pretty lucky in going the right direction, or flat out run through the place, ignoring the mobs.

We ran through the entire thing, but paused for a few seconds here or there to kill mobs when we accumulated to many. After a few dead ends we found the final room with the teleporter in it, but ran out of time right when we entered the it.

Comment: The times I've done it I rushed through to the end only briefly pausing to kill elites which I can only recommend doing if you can kill them fast.

Answer (score 8):

Its a random event. [Crumbling Vault](http://soe.hubpages.com/video/Crumbling-Vault-Event-Guide-Diablo-3) to be exact. I've only done it once successfully and it was with a monk on Hardcore, Nightmare Difficulty.

The best way to do it is with two people.  One person enters it and stays just within the entrance.  The other person rushes through to the treasure room. After the second player collects all the treasure, TP to town and than port to Player 1 just within the dungeon.  As long as you both don't wipe you will be able to enter and clear the area.  This is good for two reasons.

1. The treasure room has a lot of goodies in it, but once you enter it, you can not get back to the original area.
2. Because you had a player waiting just in the entrance, you can port, and clear the whole dungeon.  There is a lot of elite packs in dungeon along with Treasure Goblins which occasionally drop well.

Doing it this way gives you the best of both worlds :)

Answer (score 3):

in Diablo 3 Every time you enter a game, the game create a random map. Inside this map, have some dungeons, but those dungeons may be available or not, because they are also random.

Some caves have even random mobs inside.

A link that you can follow is [**Where are all the random dungeons?**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66418/where-are-all-the-random-dungeons) there is a HUGE list of dungeons.

The dungeon that you are probably talking about is

> **Stinging Winds**
>
> The Crumbling Vault (and Vault Treasure Room)

Answer (score 3):

You need to run rather quick and have some sort of shield on. I'm a level 44 Wizard, turned on my diamond armor and ran through it. I made it the first time with 1 second left. You do not have time to kill enemies, simply run as fast as you can.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, it seems to spawn in the area between khasim outpost and road to alcarnus, with a tendency to spawn wery near to where you enter the area from khasim outpost.

Answer (score 0):

It's randomized every time as you said, you simply to leave the game and resume until you get the cave again. Don't worry you won't have to wait till 3012 to get back in, I've entered it multiple times without ever seeing a hint of a ''cooldown'' on respawn.

Answer (score 0):

I won this event solo with a normal hardcore demon hunter.

At about level 20, the demon hunter gets some really valuable skills for this dungeon. The most critical are:

1. Evasive Fire with the Hardened rune. This gets you the shielding you need to allow a ranged fighter to get away with sprinting through mobs, not normally a good tactic. It also fires three shots at once and rebuilds Hatred, so it's a good fallback skill.
2. Blood Vengeance, which causes health globes to refill your Hatred, too. You will be burning through it rapidly.
3. Multishot, which is a massive scattershot effect, perfect for sweeping mobs out of your way. It costs a lot of Hatred, but the above skills fix that.
4. Rapid Fire with the Frost Shots rune to hose down a mob and slow it enough to let you punch through without spending a lot of time doing it. Use this when the mob is breaking up or pursuing single file, when Multishot is less effective.
5. Caltrops let you leave big segments of the mob behind, while you move on.

Luck also plays a role. If you go down too many blind forks, you'll lose, no matter how skilled you and your character are.