# Is it possible to get all the slabs (tiles) in the Holy Sanctum, and does it give any bonus or achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii

I always end up with one or two missing slabs (or tiles or platforms, if you prefer) in the Holy Sanctum in the 4th act.  Is it possible to get all the slabs, and is there any reason to do so?  Bonus loot?  A feat of strength achievement?

[image: Screenshot of the tiles in the Holy Sanctum]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but no, nothing interesting happens.

I completed all the slabs on my last run through this dungeon (Hell difficulty), and absolutely nothing happened other than the mobs that spawn when you step on a new slab.

Partway through, I managed to get to the far corner, where there was a Resplendent Chest waiting for me, but it definitely was there well before all of the tiles were filled in.

Comment: Recently played it in nightmare and it was just a regular chest, not even a resplendent one :\ I guess the reward is either random or depends on difficulty.

Comment: The chest is always there (in the top corner) and its type can vary (maybe depending on the difficulty, indeed, or simply chance).

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to complete it and I think I got a chest in the middle after covering all the floor with the slabs...

It didn't work for me the second time though, so there seems to be a certain way you have to cover them. I just folled the mobs spawning and somehow it worked.

Answer (score -2):

Follow the mobs.  The tiles that you can walk on will glow, that is the path you should take.

Comment: All the tiles glow when they appear.  When they appear seems to be random.

Comment: That doesn't help at all.  Moreover, I'm pretty sure the mobs appear AFTER you walk over a tile and "materialize" it.