# Where are the spawning areas in the Southern Highlands?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm trying to spawn the Abandoned Servant House and I want to be as efficient as possible but I have no idea how many possible spawning locations are in the Southern Highlands! If anyone has a map I would be most appreciative!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.diablowiki.net/File:Southern_highlands_map.jpg

it spawned in the ancient pyre zone. sometimes the door it's closed, and you have to try again.

Answer (score -2):

It spawned to the left side on the map for me.