# Can I access the locked house that can appear in the Southern Highlands?

Tags: diablo-iii

Today I've encountered a building in the Southern Highlands that looks like it should be accessible, but I did not find any way to do that. It has two doors, both can't be interacted with or destroyed. Is there a way to enter the structure, or is it just some pretty background object?

Here's how it appears on the minimap:

[image: minimap]

And here's how the inaccessible doors appear:

[image: door 1]

[image: door 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot actually open that house, or any other house that you find locked. You have a chance to find the doors open when the map is generated, so your best bet to get in is to restart the game until you find it open.

Answer (score 24):

This leads to the Abandoned Servant House random event, part of the "No Stone Unturned" achievement. Here you will find Arghus the Collector, who will sell you dyes.

[image: It's random!]

Sometimes the closed one will spawn, sometimes the open one will spawn, and other times neither will spawn.

A good place to reset and check for it is the "Trailing the Coven Khazra Barricade" quest (Act 1, quest 8, part 2).

Walk up to the barricade to get the checkpoint, then walk south and look to your right to check.

If you see rocks then chances are the house spawned (open or closed).

[image: Check]

If you see trees and tents then chances are that there is no house spawned (reset and try again).

[image: Restart]

Comment: But... how do I open the door?

Comment: @Oak you don't open the door, you can find it open randomly when you restart your game. It's like many other houses in the game, you have a chance to have them opened when you get there. If you want to be sure to get in, your best bet is to restart the game until you find it open.

Comment: @Kappei Oh. Well, that's actually the answer I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @oak It's a random event, you'll have to keep making new games until you spawn the open one. Sometimes the closed one will spawn, sometimes the open one will spawn, and other times neither will spawn. A good place to reset and check for it is the "Trailing the Coven Khazra Barricade" quest (Act 1, quest 8, part 2). Walk up to the barricade to get the check point, then walk south and look to your right to check. If you see rocks then chances are the house spawned (open or closed). If you see trees and tents then chances are that there is no house spawned (reset and try again).

Comment: I ended up accepting Kappei's answer because it was more helpful to me personally, but thank you nonetheless for a great answer!