# Where does Shaitan The Broodmother spawn?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that Shaitan spawns in The Desolate Sands, but in what area of the map does it spawn?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are all the random dungeons?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66418/where-are-all-the-random-dungeons)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shaitan the Broodmother is a unique "Great Maker" that randomly spawns in the Desolate Sands. Since the area is random, and the spawn as well, its not possible for us to give you the exact location of this.