# Are some Dungeons and Cursed Chests not always on the map?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are some achievements in Diablo 3 under the Campaign category where you're supposed to clear all cursed chests and explore all dungeons. But where are they?

I have gone through the complete map several times, but there are some dungeons and some cursed chests (presumably in the missing dungeons?) that I just can't find.

Do they only appear on the map once in a blue moon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [blue answer](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11884298579#3) for this in the official forum:

> Cursed events are similar to other events in the game. They do have
> some degree of randomness, such as where exactly in a dungeon they
> spawn (if they spawn at all).

If you are just missing some events/dungeons you can look if there exist bounties for this and start creating games until the bounty is available. When this is the case the event is guaranteed to be in your game and you even get a marker on your minimap.

Comment: Bounties? In the Adventure mode? Does that mean I can get those achievements through the adventure mode instead of playing through the campaign again and again?

Comment: Moreover, there are some things listed in Campaign achievement category that erroneously spawn only in Adventure, like Cursed Dais and Cursed Mill.

Comment: Wow, ok, that's a bit annoying... those achievements really shouldn't be under the Campaign category then O.o

Answer (score 1):

Some(if not all) *Dungeons* and *Cursed Chests* only spawn with some probability. An example would be:

- *Watch Tower* in Act 1, Southern Highlands. It doesn't always spawn, so sometimes you need to be patient

But if you want more info about these random-generated dungeons, you should take a look at [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67136/25490).

Comment: Looked at that list actually, but it didn't seem to be up-to-date.